# Is my interpretation correct that the universe of Warhammer40k is bound to cycles where great empires rise and fall?

Tags: warhammer-40k

My understanding is that:

- The Ruinous Powers aka Chaos Gods are supernatural evil beings who constantly threaten all life outside of Immaterium;
- Chaos Gods feed upon people's hatred, decadence, avarice, cruelty, etc;
- To protect against the ever present threats of attacks from followers of Chaos Gods races build mighty empires with strong military seeking to rule all who might ever want to attack them; to protect against the ever present threat of seeing their people succumb to temptations sent by Chaos Gods races will build oppressive religions that silence all dissent and forbid free thought;
- However, the very thing that ensures survival of these races, empires and religions is also precisely what gives power to their arch enemies, the Chaos Gods. Building mighty empires that seek to rule & control everything and everyone requires hubris, avarice, cruelty, ruthlessness, oppression, unbounded ambition, pride. From success stems decadence, cowardice, weakness of character and hedonism. All are precisely what Chaos Gods wish to see in their enemies.

Therefore no Empire can survive.

First there was the Empire of Eldars; we know how it ended, Eldars succumbed to decadence and it was their undoing.

Now there is the Empire of Men; similar patterns can be observed here, as the destructive Horus Heresy happened precisely at the point of Empire's greatest triumphs. Now the Empire is at an impossible situation, as it uses opression to combat the corruption of its own subjects by the Chaos Gods, but Chaos Gods feed on oppression and therefore it strengthens them to corrupt even more of Empire's subjects.

Therefore the Imperium of Men will fall. But its fall will mean that Chaos Gods will be cut not only from the greatest obstacle to their advance, but also, paradoxically, from the greatest source of their power, so they will be unable to conquer the whole universe again. As after the fall of the Eldars the universe did not revert to primordial chaos, but was eventually ruled by the Imperium of Men, so after the fall of mankind the universe will also not revert to primordial chaos, but eventually another Empire will rise, founded by whatever race will emerge strong from its ashes... and so on, and so on.

Thus, the universe is bound to endure such cycles, where Empires rise, dominate most of the universe, then fall, crumbling under their own corruption, the world reverts to a dark age from which, eventually, another empire will rise.... and so endless strife between Light and Dark must continue eternally.

Is this interpretation of Warhammer40k correct?

Comment: You base your observation on a fate of a single empire (the Eldar one). Chaos gods are not eternal,, as before the War in Heave (~65 millions years ago) Warp was a relatively peaceful place. But yes, all empires eventually fall.

Answer (score 4):

**Not Entirely**

While your thesis is right in its essentials for "current" 40k (meaning from the Fall of the Eldar to the Current 40k timeline), the Universe is not "bound" to endure these cycles for all eternity.  Indeed, during the Horus Heresy the Emperor (spoilers for the Horus Heresy book series)

> Wanted to move the entirety of mankind into the webway, thereby cutting off Chaos from its main energy source.  If this had worked the cycle would have been broken. Given what we see of this plan it both could have worked in theory and came fairly close to being workable in practice.

And the Chaos Gods were not ALWAYS there to do their chaotic thing.  Slaanesh for example was created by the ridiculous amount of hedonism in the origional Eldar Empire.  Meanwhile (spoilers for) End and the Death Part 1:

> It is stated/heavily implied near the end of End and the Death 1 that a complete Traitor victory at the Siege of Terra would have resulted in a brand-new Chaos God being created.  This implies that not just Slaanesh, but possibly ALL the chaos gods were created by discreet events in history.  Which implies that at one point the universe had no "Chaos Gods" preventing the good/evil cycle from being eternal because there would be a discreet starting point where the first chaos god appeared.

To summarize for those that don't want to read the spoilers, it is probable that, while the current state of 40k seems to be cycles of chaos ascendance/withdrawing, this was not necessarily always the case and may be something that could stop given the right circumstances.

Comment: Khorne was the first, and was born during the life of Genghis Khan. Nurgle's birth coincides with the Bubonic Plague.

Comment: @OrangeDog I'm not sure is that still correct, as it could be retconned. I think there were sources saying that the 3 major Chaos gods were "born" during the War in Heaven, ~65 millions years ago, when Old Ones as a last line of defence turned peaceful Sea of Souls into the hellhole Warp

Comment: @Yasskier is that the old Necron codex or the new one?